# Is extreme battery saving possible on Android?

Tags: root-access, battery, greenify

What is the most extreme battery saver method out there? I don't need anything (location, data, nothing) except phone calls when my screen is off. I know of greenify but even that's not good enough

I basically want to turn my android phone into a Nokia 3310 as soon as the screen turns off?

This is not just a question about app suggestion. I'm wondering if it's even possible on android. Google play services would probably not allow this sort of thing.

PS: I have a OnePlus 3 running Nougat.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app. Trigger : Screen off; 1. Action : Battery Saver on 2. Launch shortcut of Greenify *hibernate now*. That way you hibernate plus launch battery saver mode. When if your device is not rooted , there is a workaround using `adb` for action 1

Comment: What version of Android do you have?

Comment: Yes, rooted. Running Nougat.
Willing to even install a custom ROM for this.

Comment: @beeshyams I tried a similar (same?) thing with tasker. Do you think Macrodroid would differ?

Comment: What is that you didn't like with Tasker? Are you looking for something else? Or it didn't run with Tasker ? Or you are not happy that this is the best battery saving option? BTW I don't know Tasker

Comment: I am battery saving myself as you can see fro my profile . This is exactly what I have on my device - it disconnects bluetooth, data (needs root), wifi, hibernates using Greenify shortcut , which is the same as using battery saver  plus hibernation

Comment: One suggestion, you may utilise Tasker to enforce aggressive battery saving by throttling CPU, turning off  location services (secure settings) when display is off

Comment: beeshyams, I wasn't happy with the results.
@xavier_fakerat Thanks for the throttling suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're rooted and using greenify then there's this option of aggressive doze. Once try it and if not greenify then use kernel Adiutor to tweak your processor as per your need.

Comment: Good recommendation, this would be more impressive if you give instructions on  using kernel auditor to throttle CPUs

Comment: Sure, after entering into kernel Adiutor swipe left and select CPU and now you can see the cores and their respective frequencies.Just scroll down and you'll find CPU governor, now change it to Powersave. I hope there'll be Atleast a small change in the battery life!

Comment: And one more thing in case of one plus 3 i guess there are custom kernels available in XDA maybe you should give them a try!

Comment: Since OP has Tasker, it is possible to intergrate kernel auditor into tasker as a plugin of some sort (I know Tasker alone has this functionality however)

Comment: Never integrated tasker with Adiutor.Maybe you can try it yourself.